# Regex mapping text string using lists to avoid html tag overlapping

Tags: c#

> I would like to be able to map this text so I can add HTML tags
>   anywhere I later decide by searching for different words from a
>   predefined list of words. I need a solution that would allow to store
>   and work with this data. What I have in mind is to use
>   regex.matches to get the matched word index position so in the end I
>   would have mapped the whole text with their corresponding word index.
>   Now the text will not have any meaning as I'm only writing for testing
>   purposes so I would like to use this word once again.

Let's take this list of words: "I would like", "would", "word", "words"

My code so far:

```
    string text = "I would like to be able to map this text so I can add HTML tags anywhere I later decide by searching for different words from a predefined list of words. I need a solution that would allow to store thins kind of information. What I have in ming is to use regex.mactches to get the matched word index position so in the end I would have mapped the whole text with their corresponding word index. Now the text will not have any meaning as I'm only writing for testing purposes so I would like to use this word once again.";
    List<string> keywords = new List<string>(new string[] { "I would like", "would", "word", "words" });

    foreach (var k in keywords)
    {

        var foundItems = Regex.Matches(text, $@"\b{k}\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

    }
```

Looping through this list I see that `"would like"` is found twice - first at index position 0 and 2nd time at 478 and I also see it has a length of 12. Now I should store this information in a list of lists or something like a python dictionary so I can later use that data so in the end I would have the start index position of each word and by knowing it's length I can also know the ending index.

After I have this data I can decide what kind of HTML tag I will apply to each word based on my own custom filters such as number of occurences, lenght of the word or position inside the text. So for example I would say if the word is found twice I will apply the `<strong>I would like</strong>` HTML tags to the 1st one by inserting the `<strong>` to the index start position of "would like" (0) and `</strong>` to the ending index position (0 + 12 + 8) - 0 is the starting index, 12 is the length of the word and 8 is the length of the inserted html tag.

I'm doing all this because when I previously tried to simply regex.replace the words in my word list with a string containing the word wrapped with html tags I noticed that when replacing the 2n word in my list ("would") it will overlap leading to something like `<strong>I <strong>would</strong> like</strong>`.

I am asking for the best approach for storing the data described above because I want to be able to avoid the tag overlapping by removing the position of words whos index overlap.

Let's say I will store data like this:

```
new I_Would_like = {0 to 12, 478 to 490}
new would = {2 to 5,177 to 182, 325 to 330, 480 to 485)
new word = {289 to 293, 383 to 491, 503 to 507}
new words = {115 to 120, 147 to 152}
```

After adding the first html tags (`<strong>would like</strong>`) I want to mark the indexes of the text string as "occupied" so from index 0 to 20 I cannot make any more adding. If I try to add HTML tags to the 2nd word ("would") starting from the index position 2 I should see that it's "occupied" and disregard that position and move to the next one so the array **would** will have only 3 more available positions (177 to 182, 325 to 330, 480 to 485)

Please note that I cannot modify the order of the elements in my word list.

Comment: [Here's one search result](https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/139/Highlighting-Keywords-Found-In-Search-Results). I'll bet if you did a little googling, you'd find the approach that you like. Seems to be a fairly common thing to want to do.

Comment: The solution you referenced to does exactly what I am trying to avoid: Overlaps the html tags. I did my reseach on this and couldn't find anything reliable so if you have an any thoughts on this I'm all ears/eyes :)